# Getting syntax errors: JellyException: Could not parse Jelly script : null

Tags: ant, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jelly, email-ext

I am trying to read set of files ending with .errors extensions and trying to make them a part of the email sent out by jenkins via email-extension plugin. I have taken the basic html.jelly and trying to modify it. I am getting what looks like syntax errors. I don't really know how to debug it. But I went back to original and added stuff in steps. I start getting the errors when I add the ant:fileScanner

```
<j:jelly xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:st="jelly:stapler" xmlns:d="jelly:define" xmlns:ant="jelly:ant">
<BODY>
<j:set var="buildenv" value="${build.getEnvironment(listener)}"/>
<j:set var="parentWorkspace" value="${buildenv.get('PARENT_WORKSPACE')}"/>  
<ant:fileScanner var="errorFiles">              
    <ant:fileset dir="${parentWorkspace}">
        <ant:include name="*.errors" />
    </ant:fileset>
</ant:fileScanner>

<j:forEach var="errorFile" items="$(errorFiles)">
    <util:loadText file="${errorFile}" var="errorText"/>
    <TR>
      <TD>${errorText}</TD>
    </TR>
</j:forEach>

<BR/>
</BODY>
</j:jelly>
```

Any help is much appreciated. I am almost at my wits end.

EDIT: Looks like any ANT task I am trying to invoke in the jelly script is leading to errors. So looks like I am doing something wrong on ANT front. I do have ANT installed on the machine if that makes a difference.

Comment: Check whether "commons-jelly-tags-ant-1.0.jar" in classpath or not ?

Comment: Due to time constraints I took the easy way out. I used groovy based email template.

Comment: I have the same problem. Using a working html.jelly script is ok. If I copy the working html.jelly to html2.jelly and make no changes I get the "JellyException: Could not parse Jelly script : null" error. How can we debug ? Where can jelly logs be enabled/found ?